# Sharepoint permission level for list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, permissions

I have to create a list with different permission levels. I can see my list, but my teammates can't, but my manager can see all list.

I tried to use filters, but I couldn't define a filter for my manager. I was able to filter the list between teammates.

Is there any way to create groups of permissions. For example, the owners can see the full list, but the members can see their own part

Comment: You mean item level permissions? Check "Advanced settings" of the list for this.

Answer (score 0):

Access to lists or items in them is determined by permission levels. You can check permission level for particular user or group by Check permission Button on List Permission Settings page.

You should also know that there are some users that can access lists and items without explicit permission grant in list's permission list. Farm admins, Site Collection admins or users have granted access at Web application level in Central administration.